# Send a image via socket (Pillow) | Not enough image data

Tags: python, image, sockets, python-imaging-library

I am using this part of code to create the picture and send it:

```
 from PIL import ImageGrab
 s.send(ImageGrab.grab().tobytes())
```

I am using this part of code to receive the image

```
 img = con.recv(20480)  # Receive image from client
 img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (screen_width, screen_height), img) # <- ValueError: not enough image data
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your socket timeout value? You should try reading in smaller chunks and employing an *inter-chunk* timeout rather than the usual encompassing timeout.

Comment: setblocking is set to 1, so I'm pretty sure there's no timeout.